# Can't remove, hide or delete OneDrive account (from prior work employment) on PC's file explorer

Tags: windows, onedrive

I cannot remove, hide or delete a OneDrive account (from prior work employment). The message I receive is:
" The system cannot find the file specified."

Any suggestions on how I can hide it from my PC's file explorer? I want to keep using my personal OneDrive account but I would like to hide/delete my previous employer's onedrive from the file explorer.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a local login (or Microsoft account)?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods that might help:

**Method 1 : Remove OneDrive credential**

- Run *Control Panel > User Accounts*
- Click "Manage your Credentials"
- Click "Windows Credentials"
- Click on any credential that mentions OneDrive and then on Remove,
  and at the prompt click Yes
- Restart the computer.

**Method 2 : Registry update**

Registry updates should be done with care and backup.

- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`
- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and serach for OneDrive
- Continue clicking "Find next" until you fine one that says OneDrive
  in the `(Default)` item on the right
- Right-click the key name which is a long string of the format
  `{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}`
- Select Delete
- Restart the computer.